# keyboard shortcut to switch between project frames in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a keyboard shortcut to switch between project frames in intellij?

I have two projects open and the only way I've found to select the non-active project is to drag the top window/frame out of the way and then click on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've stumbled upon an intellij-native popup for switching projects. To find it and set a key mapping:

1. cmd+shift+a (if macosx; shift+shift might work cross-platform) for the find-command popup menu
2. type/search for the "open project windows" command
3. option+enter (or equiv) to assign a key mapping

This Project Windows popup lets you type to filter and select by project name.

Answer (score 82):

On osx, I use the standard keystroke (both <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd>  or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> seem to work) for switching windows within an application.

On windows, I use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>.

Comment: (Formatting: I tried to use the markdown formatting for <kbd>Command</kbd> + ... -- please supply if you know how!)

Comment: I've been putting each window in a different virtual desktop (using Spaces on the Mac), mapped to ctrl-numberKeys. What you suggest sounds even better when only 2 projects are open. I forgot about Command-tilde.

Comment: command+tilde works fine except for when IDEA windows are maximized. then I see no reaction for Command + Tilde.

Comment: On my osx [El Capitan], when two (or more) projects are open, Command + ~ switches between these projects. Problem is that when I have open diff/merge  (Webstorm) windows, I can't ever get to those with Command + ~ until I close all the projects but one. Only when one project is open, the diff/merge windows start popping up. This is a bit frustrating as I have to close all projects except for the one I work on.
Is anyone else also experiencing this behavior?

Comment: I think IntelliJ 2019 changed this to Command + Option + tilda. You can change it from Preferences > Key map > Main menu > Window > Next Project Window

Answer (score 35):

Annoyingly, you can use "**Cmd** + **`**" to switch through your windows but it doesn't loop back to the first window when you reach the end. You have to use "**Shift** + **Cmd** + **`**" to go in the reverse direction.

[image]

Comment: key mappings tend to change based on Intellij updates. This image gives clear clarity on what is the shortcut.

Answer (score 18):

for Mac OS X, try:

```
option + command + [
option + command + ]
```

Comment: question was about project windows not editor tabs.

Comment: this answer is wrong

Answer (score 16):

If you have multiple projects just switching between them may be too tedious.

In such case it's better to open `Window` menu using <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> and choose project from list.

To make **quick search** working for project names you need to open `Window` menu as popup. To do it just assign keyboard shortcut for it:

[image: keymap]

I chose <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> as my shortcut to open the following window with project quick search:

[image]

Comment: I really like this answer for the quick search feature. You could similarly bind a shortcut to the 'Open Recent' menu (cmd-shift-P for me) so that you can use the same shortcut for both opening and switching to a project.

Answer (score 12):

fast forward to 2022 and you get...

[image]

Answer (score 5):

for Windows, try:

```
Crtl + Alt + [
Ctrl + Alt + ]
```

Answer (score 5):

1. Go to Intellij **Preferences**.
2. Under **Keymap** find **Activate Next Window**.
3. Right click on it and choose **Add Keyboard Shortcut**.
4. Press **cmd + `** and click **OK**.
5. Click **OK** to close Preference window.

[Map key to Activate Next Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMa16.png)

Comment: Remaping activation of next/previous window to keyboard combo that is hardwired into your muscle memory and accurate on your own localized keyboard layout is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

**2013 answer for people who want an "up to date" answer:**

If you maximize (full screen) all your project windows and keep them grouped together in "mission control" then I find the three finger swipe works really well to move between projects.

Answer (score 2):

`Ctrl + Shift + [`

`Ctrl + Shift + ]`

Does it for me. On both Intellij IDEA and PyCharm.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows the following should work:

```
Ctrl + tab
```

Comment: That is a useful shortcut, but it switches between editor tabs in the existing projects - the question was asking to switch between projects.

Answer (score 2):

In ubuntu 18.10, you can use the below key combination for toggling betwee two open instances -

```
alt + `
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such shortcut by default, but it should be possible to implement this feature as a plug-in.

Comment: Ugh. Thanks for answering though.

I don't see an existing plugin. I suppose most people stay within the same project all day.

Answer (score 1):

In ubuntu, switching between multiple windows inside an IntelliJ, 
use alt + ~

Answer (score 1):

If you're a MacOS user, as well as the <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> and <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> keyboard shortcuts which IntelliJ offers to toggle between IntelliJ windows, the OS-level <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> keyboard shortcut is an excellent way to see and navigate between windows of the current app. The screenshot below shows the view which it offers. If you turn on App Exposé in your Trackpad preferences, you can also get to this view by swiping down with three fingers.

[image: Screenshot of showing all open windows for the current app]

Answer (score 1):

For Mac,

`Command` + `Shift` + [ or ]

works in full screen mode.

Answer (score 1):

If you have opened multiple projects and want to switch between them, then you can use:

> command `

that is, **command** and **tilde** (you can get it just above tab button).

This is for mac os.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a Mac OS X. Right click on IntelliJ dock icon shows all your open projects.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same issue. This is how I dealt with it.

If you have set up your mac for expose  ( by default F10 for application windows), then you could use that keyboard shortcut. This is the quickest way I know and since I usually have around 5 project windows I use  this fairly frequently.

Answer (score 0):

On MAC CMD + ` will work.

Ensure that you haven't maximised windows.

Answer (score 0):

Have been searching solution for macOS for long time and found this great plugin finally https://github.com/krasa/FrameSwitcher.

Switching intelliJ windows by searching project name including recent opened ones.

Answer (score 0):

I am just put a new update her for MAC OS on version (20220.1.4)
it has new:  command + option + `stands for the next and command + option + shift +` stands for back

Answer (score 0):

I am using Mac Big Sur 11.2.3 plus IntelliJ 2019. to switch among windows, I use the following 3 keys.

<kbd>⌥</kbd> <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>`</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to switch between the top and bottom frames in Zen Mode and used the following shortcut to switch between them:

<kbd>⌥</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd>